# Facebook: Issue trying to generate client code from long term oauth token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-oauth

**Background:**

[Facebook Documentation: Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#long-via-code)

Using the like above you can see Facebook's documentation for the process I am trying to accomplish.

That is, I have server API's that have already successfully authenticated and linked to a Facebook user's account and I have a long term token on our servers. Using the long term token (via server side) I am trying to generate a "client code" (as Facebook calls it) in order to send down to one of our iOS client apps. Which the client app can then use to create a long term token of it's on in order to use the SDK locally.

**Steps Taken:**

1. Documentation states that three values need to be passed in: access_token, client_secret, redirect_uri (client_secret being the application secret). This is already wrong as when only passing these values, Graph API states that client_id (otherwise known as application id) is required.
2. Passing all four values:

   - **access_token**: long term token
   - **client_id**: facebook application identifier
   - **client_secret**: facebook application secret
   - **redirect_uri**: facebook application redirect uri used when created long term session token

**Issue:**

I get the following error message returned:

```
"error": {
  "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
  "type": "OAuthException",
  "code": 1
}
```

**Questions:**

1. How do I find out what exactly the "error" that is being encountered?
2. Is there something that I am doing wrong to generate this client code?

Comment: Did you validate the long lived token in the Debugger?

Comment: Yes I did, it shows that it expires in "about 2 months" and is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "issue" was there was a bug with Facebook's code. Bug was reported, fixed and now working with no issues.